# How is it possible to check if there are untracked/ignored files on stash which does not exist anymore locally? ( git, linux )

Tags: linux, git, github

I was confused, and I called `git stash --all` and `git stash apply stash@{...}` multiple times, and also deleted some of the untracked/ignored files.

How is it possible to check, if there are files which exist in one of the stashes, but not locally?

Comment: Side note: the stashes *are* local. Everything in Git is local! Well, everything except when you have your Git call up another Git, via `git fetch` or `git push`. Then you have them transfer any commits they have that you don't, or you transfer commits you have that they don't, so that you and/or they have everything local again. After which, everything is local.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could run diff:

```
git diff --name-status stash@{10}
```

Comment: It's unfortunately necessary to peek inside each stash to see if it has a third commit. The above will merely compare the work-tree commit of each stash to things (current work-tree, in the above case).

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

You may want to use `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D stash@{number}^3` on each valid `stash@{number}`.  (To get a list of stashes, use `git stash list`.)

You may want to use `git show --name-only stash@{number}^3` on each valid `stash@{number}`.  Note that this is `git show stash@...`, not `git stash show`.

To understand which and why, read on.

## Long

What `git stash` does is a bit complicated, but it can be summarized pretty simply:

- `git stash push` (or the old spelling, `git stash save`) makes *two or three commits*, with none of the commits it makes being on any branch.  Then it runs `git reset` or `git clean` or some combination of those, depending on flags used.
- `git stash apply` *merges* some or all of the two or three commits in some stash with your existing index and work-tree.
- `git stash pop` means *run `git stash apply`, and then if that claims to succeed, run `git stash drop`*.

Unfortunately, the above is actually pretty complex—it requires that you understand Git's usage of the *index*, for one thing–and yet is incomplete.  It says that `git stash push` makes two commits (or sometimes three), but it does not say what is *in* those commits, nor what form they have in your repository.  For the simplest usage of `git stash`, none of those matter too much, but for your case, they are crucial.

#### Commits

I'll just mention these briefly since, aside from the ones that `git stash` makes, we're not too concerned with them.  Each commit holds a complete snapshot of files.  Exactly *which* files, we'll see in a moment.  Along with the snapshot, the commit contains some metadata, including who made the commit, when (date-and-time-stamp), and why (log message).  Each commit has a unique hash ID, and as part of the metadata, each commit includes the hash ID of its parent—a link back to the previous commit.

A *merge* commit has links back to two or more parents.  Commits that are linked this way are normally closely related—which is why the linkage is parent/child, after all—but unlike the snapshot-plus-metadata part, there's no hard requirement that the files in any one commit relate much to those in any other.  We'll see that in a moment, with the stash commits, too.

Besides being identified by their hash IDs, commits are mostly permanent—though of course stash commits are intended to be non-permanent and will eventually go away after being dropped—and are completely read-only.  This means that they cannot be used to do any *new* work, which is why Git has more than just commits.  This is *why* you need a work-tree.

#### The index and the work-tree

As we just noted, the commits are read-only.  Not only that, the files stored in each commit are in a special, compressed, read-only format.  This means two or more commits can *share* a file that's the same in both commits, which in turn means that even if you commit some version of a file hundreds of times, Git only has to store it once.  I like to refer to these internal format files as freeze-dried.

In order for you to actually use or change your files, Git has to rehydrate them, turning them back into ordinary files that you can read and write.  The area in which commits are rehydrated for your use is your *work-tree*.  Git could stop here—with frozen commits holding dehydrated files, as permanent as the commits themselves, plus temporary, ephemeral, but useful work-tree files.  Other version control systems *do* stop here: you have, at any time, the freeze-dried copy of a file in the current commit, plus the useful one in the work-tree.  But for various reasons, Git adds a *third* copy of the file.  This extra copy sits *between* the commit and the work-tree, in what Git calls, variously, the *index* or the *staging area*.

The extra copy of each file that's in the index, between the frozen dehydrated copy in the current commit and the useful copy in the work-tree, is also in the dehydrated form.  The key difference between it and the current-commit copy is that it's *not* read-only.  You can overwrite it—though technically this just moves the previous one out of the way—with a new freeze-dried copy at any time.  That's what `git add` does: it freeze-dries the work-tree copy and uses that to overwrite the index copy.

This is *why* you have to `git add` files all the time.  They're already there, in the index, ready to commit—but they match the one that came *out* of the last commit.  You've modified the work-tree copy, but the frozen copy hasn't changed—of course not, it's frozen—and neither has the index copy, which matches the committed copy.  So now you have to re-compress the updated file and *replace* the index copy.  You run `git add updated.ext` and Git does just that.  Now your index and work-tree match, and differ from the frozen copy.

When you run `git commit`, Git looks not at your *work-tree* but at your *index*.  Whatever is in your index *right then*, Git packs those (already freeze-dried) files into a new commit, and that new commit becomes your current commit.  Now your index and commit match, because the new commit was made *from* the index.

This is also what determines whether a file is *tracked*.  If there is a copy in the index, the file is tracked.  The tracked copy—the one in the index—will be in the next commit, if you make it right now.  If you have a file in your work-tree that *isn't* in your index, that file is *untracked*.  That file *won't* be in the next commit, if you make it right now.  Hence the index is, in a way, the *proposed next commit*.  Every time you update it with `git add`, you're proposing to commit something slightly different.

Files that are untracked normally make various Git commands—especially `git status`—*complain*.  You can shut up these complaints, and also make `git add --all` not copy the files *into* the index, by listing some or all of these files in a `.gitignore`.  Note that listing a *tracked* file has no effect: it's already there in the index, so there's no question of ignoring it: it's *not* ignored.  Being listed in `.gitignore` only affects *untracked* files, and basically just makes it hard to accidentally track them, and shuts up `git status` about them.

You can put *new* files into the index at any time, using `git add`.  If the file wasn't there before, `git add` creates it in the index, rather than displacing the previous copy.  You can also *remove* files *from* the index at any time, using either `git rm`—this removes the file from the index *and* the work-tree—or `git rm --cached`, which removes the file from the index only.  At `git commit` time, it doesn't matter *how* a file is or isn't in the index, only *whether* it is or is not there, and if it is there, with what freeze-dried content.

It's worth a brief look at how `git commit` makes a new commit now.  When you run `git commit`, as we already mentioned, Git stuffs all the tracked files into a new commit.  First, though, Git gathers up the *metadata:* your name (from `user.name`), your email address (from `user.email`), the current date-and-time, and your log message.  Git also knows which commit is the *current* commit.  That commit's hash ID goes into the parent hash ID for the new commit.  And then Git saves the index and makes the commit, which automatically gets a new, unique hash ID.  As the last step of `git commit`, Git then writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *current branch name*.

Hence if you used to have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

with commit `H` as the current commit, and you've just made new commit `I`, new commit `I` points back to `H`, and Git has shoved the hash ID of `I` into the branch name `master`, so now you have:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

#### Now we can look at what `git stash push` does

When `git stash` builds a new stash *without* `--all`, it:

1. Writes out the index as a commit.  This is really easy since that's what `git commit` already does.  All Git has to do is *not* update the name `master` (and supply a log message for you, which it does).  Let's write out a commit `i` (lowercase) and *not* put it on `master`.  Instead, we'll remember it with a temporary variable:

   ```
   ...--F--G--H   <-- master
              |
              i   <-- $tempvar
   ```
2. Writes out the *work-tree* as a commit.  This is tricky to do efficiently, and also requires another special trick at the end.  Without going into the details of *how* `git stash` manages writing the work-tree, it's worth saying that this only writes *tracked* files.  The trick at the end is that `git stash` sets things up so that this new commit, which we'll call `w`, has *two* parents instead of one.  The first parent of `w` will be `H` and the *second* parent of `w` will be `i`:

   ```
   ...--F--G--H   <-- master
              |\
              i-w   <-- stash
   ```

With these two commits written out, Git updates the special name `refs/stash` to remember the hash ID of commit `w`.

This stash has no untracked files, regardless of whether they're ignored.  Commit `i` was made *from* the index, so it has no untracked files by definition.  The process that Git uses to make `w` only stores files that are in the index, so it has no untracked files either.

If you use `git stash push --all`, `git stash push --include-untracked`, or the `git stash save` flavors of these same commands, Git modifies the saving process a bit.  It makes commit `i` as usual, but then it makes a commit I call `u`, to hold the *untracked* files.  This extra commit either holds *just* the untracked files, excluding the untracked-and-ignored files, or it holds *all* the untracked files including the ignored ones.  This commit has *no* parent listed (which is a good trick, but easy to do when you use the Git *plumbing* commands, as `git stash` did before it was converted to C code recently); it just floats out there on its own:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
           |
           i   <-- $i_commit

           u   <-- $u_commit
```

Now `git stash save` goes back to its main path and makes commit `w`, but this time it gives `w` *three* parents: the current commit `H`, the index commit `i`, and the untracked-files commit `u`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
           |\
           i-w   <-- stash
            /
           u
```

#### Quick recap: what's in i, w, and u

Commit `i` holds the index state.  There are, by definition, no untracked files in `i`.  Commit `w` holds the work-tree state, again without untracked files.  If commit `u` exists—it's optional, after all—it holds the untracked files, *but no tracked files:* the stash code parsimoniously saves those only in `i` and `w`.

#### Now `git stash push` cleans up

Having saved files in two or three commits, the last step of `git stash push` is to *reset* the index and work-tree.  *If* you told `git stash` to create commit `u`, it also *removes* from the work-tree any file it saved in commit `u`.

The reset of index and work-tree is normally done by a simple `git reset --hard`.  This leaves the index and work-tree in a state that matches the current commit `H`.  If you made the `u` commit, its files are now gone from the work-tree, otherwise those files are untouched in the work-tree.

However, `git stash push` (unlike `git stash save`) has the ability to reset less than the entire work-tree.  In that case, it's all done by a more complex bit of code.  You can also (well, instead) throw in the option `--keep-index`, in which case, instead of `git reset --hard` or similar, Git checks out what's in commit `i`, so that the work-tree matches `i`.  (It leaves the index itself alone, so `i` and the index continue to match.)  None of this affects your immediate task, but all of it affects the ability to *restore* one of these stashes.

#### Previous stashes get "stacked"

When `git stash push` is done, the new stash is the one identified by `refs/stash`, or just `stash` for short.  You can also describe this as `stash@{0}`, if you like.  Any *existing* stashes are moved up one, to `stash@{1}`, `stash@{2}`, and so on: what was `stash@{1}` becomes `stash@{2}`, etc.

The mechanism behind this is Git's *reflogs*, which apply to all references: branches have `master@{1}`, `master@{2}`, and so on, too.  The stash code just (ab?)uses these to implement the stash stack.  Other reflogs are insert-only: there's no "pop the n'th master" command.

#### Restoring a stash

When you choose to apply a stash—with `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`; remember that the latter is just apply-then-drop—you tell Git *which* stash to use, using `stash@{number}` for instance.  This points directly to a `w` commit, but the `w` commit allows you to reach its `i` commit and, if it exists, its `u` commit.  The easy way to do that is to use [the gitrevisions syntax for graph-walking](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  For instance, to refer to commit `i`, which is the second parent of `w`, you can write:

```
stash^2
```

because `stash` points to commit `w` and `w`'s second parent is `i`.  If commit `u` exists in this stash, `stash^3` will name it.

Hence, `git stash apply` first looks to see whether a `u` commit exists.  If so, `git stash` *insists* on restoring it.  Restoring a `u` commit *requires* that none of the files *in* `u` exist in the work-tree right now.

What this means is that if you have a bunch of untracked files, and you're not sure which ones are in `u`, you can just remove (or move-out-of-the-way) *all* untracked files.  That's by far the simplest thing to do.  If you want to be carefully selective, you will need to list out the names of the files that are in commit `u`, and there's no front-end user-facing command for that.  You *can* do it though, in multiple ways, as we'll see in a moment.

In any case, Git definitely has commits `i` and `w`.  (The `git stash` code makes sure there are two such commits, plus the optional third `u` commit, and rejects your command-line argument if not.)  So `git stash apply` needs to go about restoring `i` and `w` too.  The way it does this is:

1. Save the current index state.  This prevents applying a stash if you're in a conflicted merge that you have not concluded.
2. Unless you used `--index`, *completely ignore* commit `i`.  Otherwise, compare `i` vs `w`'s first parent—the commit that *was* current at the time you saved the stash—using `git diff`.  Send the diff to `git apply --cached`.  Technically, the actual line of code in the old `git-stash` script is:

   ```
   git diff-tree --binary $s^2^..$s^2 | git apply --cached
   ```

   (`$s` is commit `w` so this uses `i^` rather than `w^` but `i^` and `w^` are the same; the diff uses `diff-tree --binary` so that it always works right, as plain diff won't diff binary files, and will use your per-user configuration, which is a bad idea here).

   The apply step may fail.  If so, `git stash apply --index` fails and does nothing.  If the apply step succeeds, save the resulting index for later, then use `git reset` to reset it to match the `HEAD` commit.

   There's also a fancy trick here: Git checks whether the saved index in step 1 matches the saved index in the stash.  If so, the index already has the right contents and there's no point in doing the `git apply --cached`.  This is not *just* an optimization; it's useful with `git stash --keep-index`: it makes `git stash apply --index` work for that case.  (Of course, *you* could run `git stash apply` without `--index`, if your index already matches the stash's `i`, but my guess is someone thought that was too unfriendly.)
3. Use the merge machinery to combine commit `w` with your current work-tree, using `w`'s first parent as the merge base.  I won't go into details here, but this part can be quite messy.  If there are merge conflicts here, and the current work-tree *did not* match the `HEAD` commit when you started, it can be extremely difficult to get back to the state you were in.

   (This is one of several reasons that I recommend avoiding `git stash` in general.  It *is* safe to use `git stash` in many cases, and if you really know what you're doing, you know how to make things safe for yourself in all cases.  But `git stash` is advertised as a quick and easy solution for Git newbies, and in fact, it's not at all quick, nor easy, in these corner cases!)

#### Your case (finally!)

In your case, you have run several `git stash push --all` operations, so you have several to many stashes—`stash@{0}` through `stash@{9}`, say, or maybe even more—some or all of which have `u` commits, which you can access via `stash@{number}^3`.

These `u` commits have no parent, so if you run:

```
git show stash@{1}^3
```

for instance, Git will compare, i.e., `git diff`, the [*empty tree*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) to the `u` commit for `stash@{1}`.  This will show the files (and the contents of the files—add `--name-only` to get just the names) in that `u` commit.

That could be what you want!  That shows you a list of which files are in the `u` commit for that stash.  That's not quite what you asked for, though:

> ... if there are files which exist in one of the stashes, but not locally

By "locally" here I assume you mean in your existing work-tree as it stands *right now*, without adding or removing any files to it.

If we run:

```
git diff <commit-specifier>
```

with no additional options, Git will compare the contents of the specified commit to the contents of the work-tree.  The current index plays no role in this diff, though the contents of `.gitignore` do.  The files of interest are:

- those in the given commit
- those in the work-tree, whether or not they exist in the given commit, minus any files that (a) do exist in the work-tree and (b) are listed in `.gitignore`.

That is, suppose we name a commit—such as one of these `u` commits—that contains files `a.ext`, `b.ext`, and `c.ext`.  Your current work-tree either has an `a.ext` or does not; the same goes for `b.ext` and `c.ext`.  Your current work-tree also has `d.ext` and `e.bin`, neither of is in this `u` commit.

If file `a.ext` does not exist in your current work-tree, `git diff` will claim that, to convert commit `u` to match your work-tree, you should *delete* `a.ext`.  If file `b.ext` *does* exist in your work-tree and matches that in `u`, Git will say nothing about it.  If file `c.ext` *does* exist, but doesn't match the copy in `u`, Git will say that `c.ext` is modified, and to make `c.ext` in commit `u` make `c.ext` in your work-tree, particular lines need to be added and/or deleted: that's the diff instruction output.

Since `d.ext` *does* exist in your work-tree, `git diff` will say that to convert `u` to match your work-tree, you should *add* `d.ext`, with its current contents.  If `*.bin` is ignored, though, `git diff` won't tell you how to add it to commit `u`: the assumption here is that you don't want to make a new commit that's like `u` but has `e.bin` added, as `e.bin` is to be ignored.  That's true *even if `e.bin` is in your index right now.*  While `git commit` cares, this particular `git diff` doesn't.

Since commit `u` in each stash lists all (and only) the files saved in it, any instruction from Git that tells you that you must *delete* some file from `u` in order to make it match your work-tree, tells you that the file exists in `u` and not in your work-tree.  So we use `--diff-filter=D` to make `git diff` mention file `a.ext`.  This filter will exclude `c.ext`, as it does exist: it just has the wrong contents.  The set of files that `git diff` would report therefore consists solely of `a.ext`, which is in `u` but not in your work-tree.  The `--name-only` option makes `git diff` print just the file name, and not the actual instructions for converting the file.

---

There are still more ways to handle this problem, but these two—`git show` or `git diff` with `--name-only` and additional options if / as needed, plus a name for the stash's `u` commit—seem like the simplest.